# Get state from terratest and run manually terraform destroy?

Tags: terraform, terratest

I make test with Terratest but I set wrong timeout and now test failed and resources are still there. I can remove them manually but better way will be using terraform destroy.

Is there way how get state or save them during running test via Terratest?

Answer (score 0):

Terratest essentially just runs `terraform` commands with the parameters you give it in your local folder structure.

So, you should just be able to change directories to the module run by terratest (i.e. the [`TerraformDir`](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/master/test/terraform_aws_lambda_example_test.go#L25-L27)) and run typical terraform commands (e.g. `terraform plan`, `terraform destroy`).

If you're asking about having the terratest do the destroy automatically for you, you can do that by passing along the same options to `terraform.Destroy` as in [this example](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terratest/blob/master/test/terraform_aws_lambda_example_test.go#L41). The `defer` is recommended so that destruction happens after you have validated your resources.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  But in the output, it tells you the temporary folder where it's putting everything to run. It also had the state file.  I was able to run a terraform destroy from that temp folder!

Answer (score 0):

We have a couple approaches to tackle this issue:

1. Increase the Go test timeout by adding flag `go test -timeout 1h`
2. Increase the task and job timeout in the pipeline.
3. Use the [test_structure](https://terratest.gruntwork.io/docs/testing-best-practices/iterating-locally-using-test-stages/) "framework" from TerraTest with skippable Stages (env `SKIP_<name of stage>`). With the test_structure you can defer the destroy and will *always run.
4. Custom post cleanup script step in the build that run always, unless the destroy is skipped. The custom script will reset peerings, private endpoints and even clear state files.

*Not always, in case of a bigger issue, a timeout for example.